# Get active index from material collapsible

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I want to get the index of the active in a materialcss collapse.

I have tried with the following code

```js
function getActive() { return($('.active').data("index")) } $(document).ready(function(){ $('.collapsible').collapsible(); });
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function:

```
function getActive() { return $('.active').index(); }
```